# Query to fetch latest records in the coming years fetches the newly added data as well

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I add a new user to the system in a employee management system. Now lets say I store the users joining dates as 26-12-2018, i.e today's date.Now I try to fetch the upcoming work anniversaries of all the users. The users that is currently added also shows up in upcoming work anniversary. This is wrong as the user is just added and obviously his work anniversary is not due till the next year.

Here is my query,

```
SELECT  
    "users".* 
FROM 
    "users" 
    INNER JOIN "groups_users"
        ON "groups_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
    INNER JOIN "groups"
        ON "groups"."id" = "groups_users"."group_id" 
WHERE 
    "users"."organisation_id" = 24 
    AND "users"."status" = 1     
    AND ("users"."joining_date" IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY
    users.id  
ORDER BY 
    (to_char(to_date((to_char(current_date,'yyyy')
        || to_char(joining_date,'-MM-DD')), 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date,'ddd')::int
        - to_char(current_date,'ddd')::int
        + to_char((to_char(current_date,'yyyy')||'-12-31')::date,'ddd')::int)
        % to_char((to_char(current_date,'yyyy')||'-12-31')::date,'ddd')::int,
    first_name 
LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0
```

Now if I add a new user named Ramesh Mesta today, i.e 26-12-2018
, this returns the following set

```
746 "Ramesh" "Mesta"    
7056 "Tavira" "danial"  
7057 "Bired" "leve" 
6918 "cIvankatrump" "Trumphivsnka"
```

Having Ramesh Mesta does not makes sense here since he was just created.
Amy Help

Comment: What is an “upcoming anniversary”, you have not defined that in your question or tried to define it in your query?

Comment: Also what database is this, you have tagged your question with several? I’ll remove them and then you can re-add the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ORDER BY` logic doesn't really work effectively for getting upcoming anniversaries, I suggest dropping it and using the below `WHERE` clause and just do `ORDER BY` on `joining_date`. Add this to your exisiting `WHERE` clause, I have used 10 days (355 = 365 - 10) as my interpretation of "upcoming" but you can of course change this if you want a different span.

```
(current_date - joining_date) % 365  > 355
```

Note that this doesn't include todays anniversaries so if you want that to you need to OR like

```
   (current_date - joining_date) % 365  > 355
OR (current_date - joining_date) % 365 = 0
```

`ORDER BY` can now be simplified to

```
ORDER BY joining_date ASC
```